# Excluding certain MDI child windows from cascading

Tags: delphi, mdi

I have written an MDI app with many child forms, each different. Let's say that the user has created three child forms: the first form has its top left hand corner at screen coordinates 0,0; a second form has been dragged to the right hand side of the screen (coordinates 100, 300) and the third form appears at coordinates 20,20. If I use the main form's cascade command, then the second form will move to 10,10.

I would like the second form to stay where it is and get the third form to move to 10, 10 (ie second place of cascading order). Is there any way of excluding specific MDI child forms from the main form's 'Cascade' command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to influence the behaviour of the `Cascade` method which is implemented by sending a [`WM_MDICASCADE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the MDI container window, `ClientHandle`.

Now, looking at `WM_MDICASCADE` it has an option to skip disabled MDI children from cascading. So you could disable certain child windows, send a `WM_MDICASCADE` message yourself and then re-enable the child windows. I've not attempted to do this but it seems very likely to me that it would work.

Your other option is to implement your own MDI child positioning method. This is actually relatively easy to do. I would suggest that you consult the source code for the [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) project to get an idea how to do this. The key file is `mdi.c` in the `user32` DLL.

Comment: To which form would I send the wm_mdicascade message, to the main form or to the child forms?

Comment: Send it to `MainForm.ClientHandle` which is the window representing the MDI container. Read the source of `TForm.Cascade` to see how the VCL does it.

Comment: I've written up the complete solution on my blog - http://nbnewman.blogspot.com/2011/12/preventing-mdi-creep-how-to-decascade.html

Comment: Have you considered the solution 99% of us chose years ago; Stop using MDI. It sucks.

Comment: 99% of applications I've seen that have a "multiple document interface" style use docking or some other approach to emulating MDI without using the windows 3.1 era MDI code in windows, with its myriad glitches.

Comment: @WarrenP I guess it's just me ploughing a lone furrow then!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's funny to provide the link but not to the actual code and instead to the home page for the project. :) Here's the [link to the actual source code](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/user32/mdi.c#L680). Scroll down to `MDICascade()` function.